# Random walk algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, random

I'm trying to create a program which plots the different paths and points which you can take on the Cartesian plane using the following algorithm:
Starting from the origin (0, 0), in step 1, you do one of the following:

*jump 1/2 to the right or 1/2 to left or terminate where you are.

If the movement hasn't ended yet, then in step 2:

*jump 1/4 upwards or 1/4 downwards or terminate where you are.

If the movement hasn't ended yet, then in step 3:

*jump 1/8 to the right or 1/8 to the left or terminate where you are,etc.

You would essentially do this indefinitely, where in step k, if k is even and the movement has not end yet, you would jump (1/2)^k upwards or downwards. Similarly, in step k if k is odd you jump (1/2)^k to the right or left or terminate where you are.

I want to plot the set of endpoints you can reach in this way in finitely many steps. Is the following code correct? By the way,the coloured circles at the end of each path is an endpoint. Are these plotted correctly?

```
import numpy
import pylab
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
axes = plt.axes()
k = 50

x = numpy.zeros(k)
y = numpy.zeros(k)
lst = []
for j in range(1,30):
  for i in range(1,k):
    dir = [-1,1][random.randint(0,1)]
    if i%2!=0:
        x[i] = x[i - 1] + 1/(2**(i)) * dir
        y[i] = y[i - 1]
    else:
      x[i] = x[i - 1]
      y[i] = y[i - 1] + 1/(2**(i)) * dir
  plt.plot(x, y,marker = 'o')
plt.title("Different paths the random walk movement sequences could take")
pylab.show()
```

[image: Graph of possible paths plotted]

Comment: Why do you have a doubt? Is there a problem?

Comment: I just wanted to confirm if this is correct, that's all.

Comment: If what you want is to plot _all_ the possible paths, please rephrase your question. After running your code, I noticed that for large k, only one branch is shown. Alternatively, if what you want is to show _one_ possible path, please also state so.

Comment: Is the output not what you expected? What are you missing to judge yourself whether it is what you wanted or not?

Comment: There's no reason to use random numbers if you're trying to plot all the paths that could be taken.  If k is 10, then there are over 1000 paths, but you're only going to plot 30 of them?

Comment: I was not sure how to account for each possible jump at a given step, so I used random numbers to account for this. Also how is it plotting 30 paths?

Answer (score 1):

I think some aspects were missing from the code you posted, such as whether or not any given walk will terminate. Your code is placing a marker at each step , rather than at just the end. I've sought to implement the functionality you've described by adapting your code.

[image]

Console output:

```
Walk 0
 at step 1 moves 1/2^2 along x
 terminates at step 2
Walk 1
 at step 1 moves 1/2^2 along x
 at step 2 moves 1/2^3 along y
 terminates at step 3
Walk 2
 at step 1 moves 1/2^2 along x
 at step 2 moves 1/2^3 along y
 at step 3 moves 1/2^4 along x
 terminates at step 4
Walk 3
 at step 1 moves 1/2^2 along x
 at step 2 moves 1/2^3 along y
 at step 3 moves 1/2^4 along x
 at step 4 moves 1/2^5 along y
 terminates at step 5
Walk 4
 at step 1 moves 1/2^2 along x
 terminates at step 2
```

Implementation:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#walk parameters
steps_per_walk = 50
n_walks = 5
termination_prob = 0.2

#Each walk will have a colour
colour_map = plt.get_cmap('jet', n_walks)

numpy.random.seed(4) #make the randomness reproducible

for walk in range(n_walks):
    #Each walk starts at (0, 0)
    x = [0]
    y = [0]
    
    print('Walk', walk)
    
    for step in range(1, steps_per_walk + 1):
        step_size = 1 / 2 ** step
        
        #Chance of terminating at any given step
        terminates = True if numpy.random.rand() < termination_prob else False
        
        if terminates:
            #No more steps will be taken in this walk
            print(' terminates at step', step)
            break
        
        #Otherwise, movement will be either +step or -step with equal prob
        movement = step_size * [-1, 1][numpy.random.randint(2)]
        
        #Moving from previous point:
        x.append( x[step - 1] )
        y.append( y[step - 1] )
        
        #Move alternately along x for first step, then y
        if step % 2 != 0:
            x[step] += movement
        else:
            y[step] += movement
            
        print(' at step', step, f'moves 1/2^{step + 1}',
              'along', 'y' if not step % 2 else 'x')
            
    #Plot the walk's recorded path
    plt.plot(x, y, color=colour_map(walk), label=f'walk {walk} ({step - 1} steps)')
    #Add marker only at the walk's end point
    plt.plot(x[-1], y[-1], color=colour_map(walk), marker='s')
    
    #loops over remaining walks until all walks done...

plt.title("Different paths the random walk\nmovement sequences could take")
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.4, 1))
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(7, 3)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Ah I see, well I thought each step could be a possible endpoint, since you can terminate at any step.

Comment: I see, I misunderstood your initial comments. Your diagram seems correct to me. If you remove the `'o'` and add `marker='x'` that'll help you see the individual markers a bit more.